# Performing segue with UINavigationController (without IBAction)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

It's easier to show you a drawing and then explain.

[image]

**Dashboard Storyboard**

I have 2 separate `UIViewControllers` (i've included just one in the drawing, the other is irrelevant) embedded in container view called `ContainerViewController`.

**Post Storyboard**

`NewPostViewController` shows a `UIButton` that presents `TextPostViewController`. As you can see, all of them are embedded in `UINavigationControllers`. Now, once the completion block of the new post is being called, I have to present the `ContainerViewController` and it needs to handle it's own logic. The problem is that it's embedded in `UINavigationController` and once I present it, the `UITaBbar` is hidden.

I tried to do this:

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TextPostToNavContainerVC", sender: nil)`

The transition is successful but I'm losing the UITabBar, even though in the `DashboardViewController` and the `ContainerViewController` I called:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

}
```

What am I doing wrong or is there are better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should instantiate the tab bar controller. not the view controller.
Imagine you're putting a initial view controller ahead of your tab bar controller. Making your tab bar not being pushed

If I undestand it correctly.
You are doing this
[Segue connect to a view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCp73.png)
But you should actually do this [Segue connected to a tab bar controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCu2B.png)

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: The entire project is based on Multiple storyboards and I'm using Storyboard References so it's easier to manage the View controllers. Which storyboard you'd like to see?

Comment: Oh, Jesus! Yes. I finally got what you were saying. I'm sorry I'm a bit slow after 9 hours of coding. Yes, that's what I was trying to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add it as a child to control it's frame like this

```
let textPost = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "containerID") as! TextPostToNavContainerVC
textPost.view.frame =  CGRect(x:20,y:0,width:self.view.frame.width,height:self.view.frame.height-50)
self.view.addSubview(nvc.view)
self.addChildViewController(textPost)
textPost.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```